# I want to take an input from a user but receive only numbers.in Python

Tags: python, input, numbers

i am trying to make a program were a user will input his phone. I want him to be able to write only numbers and if he writes a letter then it will either delete the character he just wrote or "lock" his keyboard to only numbers. I am currently using a try/except in order to work but still i want to know if there is a library or a function that allows me to give access to only certain keys to the user.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not use a loop that verify all the characters are digits?

Comment: Will that verify the moment he writes each character or after he finishes the whole input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` to loop the input till the user inputs only number:

```
def getInput():
    value = input("Please enter number: ")
    while not value.isnumeric():
        print("Invalid number")
        value = input("Please enter valid number: ")
    return int(value)
getInput()
```

Comment: I am pretty new to programming so i am not sure what i am thinking is capable for python. What i am trying to say is that i check the moment he writes a character if it is a number or something else and if it is not number to either delete his last character or "lock" the letters in the keyboard

Comment: @NikolasIatrou Yes I understood what you are trying to convey. I just suggested another approach by which you can do this. Handling the user input during runtime is not poss as far as I know.

Comment: If you get to know the way to solve as per your needs, please let us know too.

Comment: I will definitely upload it if i manage to find a solution to that!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "restrict" the keys a user can type with the `input()` function itself. You could (as far as I can tell - I didn't try actually) get this result on unix-like systems using the `curses` module, but you'll need some external lib to make it work on Windows. And in all cases, it will requires much more coding (curses is not exactly a simple, modern UI lib).

As a side note, a phone number can contains non numeric characters (think of international phone numbers) ;-)

Comment: That is true, it may contain non numeric characters but i thought that if i could find a solutions to restrict him to numeric character i could allow him to use 2-3 more characters. Anyway, thank you very much for you time, i will check the curses module!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop an input like that, but you can use a try-except statement. 
 Either by asking for the input again or returning a print error.

```
try:
    user_input = int(input("Number input: "))
except ValueError:
    user_input = int(input("Number input: "))
```

Similarly, if you want this to repeat until the user inputs a number you can use a while loop and break.

```
while True:
    try:
        user_input = int(input("Number input: "))
        if int(user_input):
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Input is not an number")
```